# No columns were bound prior to calling SQLFetch

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, idiorm, intersystems-iris

I am currently working on a project with the following techstack:

- Database: Intersystems IRIS
- Controller: PHP/PDO with IdiORM

The problem is that the IDs are not in a common format.

For example:

```
ABX||242149||1||0||D
```

So there are different keys seperated with `||` as delimiter.

As long as the ID's are like `232||ABH` the request with IdiORM is working but an ID like the first example gives the error message:

> No columns were bound prior to calling SQLFetch"

PHP code:

```
class TestController
{
    public function test()
    {
        $out=IRIS::for_table('')->raw_query("select id from Bestand where artikelnr='430030'")->find_array();
        echo json_encode($out);
    }
}
```

Are there any restrictions for IdiORM due to the ID format? It seems like the ORM cant map the given ID to the ID column?